# Server 2016 DNS // Forward DNS request to parent domain if not available in subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

Is it possible to forward DNS requests to the parent domain (managed by the same server) if there's no entry in a subdomain?

Eg. requesting `foo.nyc.acme.lan` would automatically forward to `foo.acme.lan` if there is no `foo` in the `nyc.acme.lan` zone.

Nameserver is a windows server 2016 and right now we are solving the desired behaviour with multiple DNS suffixes in the DNS search list on the client side. But that approach doesn't apply to all clients so a server sided solution would be better.

Comment: If you are talking about resolution for single-label short names, it is possible to use DNS Devolution, but that is disabled if you are using a group policy defined DNS Suffix Search Order. You need to use one or the other.

Comment: Yeah we have that in place for unqualified name resolution. Just read up DNS Devolution and as it is (if I understand it correctly) also configured on the client that won't help us as it still is windows only and needs full control on the client. We are looking for a silber bullet that works with linux / osx as well and is configured on the nameserver.

Comment: If this is for single-label names that don't change much you could use the GlobalNames zone.

Comment: Nah that won't work unfortunately. To give you a bit more context: 
We have multiple sites. Some hosts/services are different per site so they exist in each zone (eg. database.nyc.acme.lan and database.la.acme.lan). Others are used "globally" on all sites and live in acme.lan (e.g. service.acme.lan). 
For convenience we let our users access services/hosts with its unqualified name (db / service in the exmaples above). To access the `service` host, acme.lan has to be in ther search suffix list though. OR .. and thats where I am coming from the name-server would forward it automatically ;)

Comment: addendum: we also use the sub-domain as override in some cases. So there might be a `foo.acme.lan` but in LA `foo` has to point to antoher ip. -> Put a `foo.la.acme.lan` record in the respective zone.   
I am quite sure there are much more elegant ways to accomplish such things but thats how it is setup right now and a lot of it is due to a merge of two originally independent domains

Comment: You may be able to use DNS policies to resolve the names differently for some of the scenarios.